MariaDB 10 -> 11 migration, the 11th version stopped using possible_keys
I faced the issue during migration from MariaDB 10.11 to 11.0 version that some specific queries run longer.
During running EXPLAIN output I got this.
MariaDB 10.11
MariaDB [my_schema]> EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `article_data_view`.`esl` AS `esl` FROM `article_data_view` GROUP BY `article_data_view`.`esl` ORDER BY `article_data_view`.`esl` ASC LIMIT 1000;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                               | key                                    | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra                                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | a     | range  | PRIMARY,FK_articleinfo_id                   | FK_articleinfo_id                      | 5       | NULL                       | 103925 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ai    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                     | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.a.articleinfo_id |      1 | Using index                                            |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ref    | FK_order_customerid,FK_order_articleid      | FK_order_articleid                     | 4       | my_schema.a.ID             |      1 |                                                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_cu,id_userid                     | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.o.customerid     |      1 |                                                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                     | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.c.userid         |      1 | Using index                                            |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | addr  | ref    | FK_address_customer,Idx_address_addresstype | FK_address_customer                    | 5       | my_schema.o.customerid     |      1 | Using where                                            |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ami   | ref    | PRIMARY,FK_articlemediafile_fileid          | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.a.ID             |     13 | Using where; Using index                               |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | amf   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,filetype,filetype_sortorder         | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.ami.fileid       |      1 | Using where                                            |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | api   | ref    | FK_custom_key_id                            | FK_custom_key_id                       | 4       | my_schema.a.ID             |      1 |                                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0,015 sec)

MariaDB 11
MariaDB [my_schema]> EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `article_data_view`.`esl` AS `esl` FROM `article_data_view` GROUP BY `article_data_view`.`esl` ORDER BY `article_data_view`.`esl` ASC LIMIT 1000;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                               | key                                    | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ALL    | FK_order_customerid,FK_order_articleid      | NULL                                   | NULL    | NULL                       | 214315 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_articleinfo_id                   | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.o.articleid      | 1      | Using where                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_cu,id_userid                     | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.o.customerid     | 1      |                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ai    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                     | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.a.articleinfo_id | 1      |                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                     | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.c.userid         | 1      |                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | addr  | ref    | FK_address_customer,Idx_address_addresstype | FK_address_customer                    | 5       | my_schema.o.customerid     | 3      | Using where                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ami   | ref    | PRIMARY,FK_articlemediafile_fileid          | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.o.articleid      | 24     | Using where                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | amf   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,filetype,filetype_sortorder         | PRIMARY                                | 4       | my_schema.ami.fileid       | 1      | Using where                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | api   | ref    | FK_custom_key_id                            | FK_custom_key_id                       | 4       | my_schema.o.articleid      | 1      |                                 |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+

As you may notice at version 10 it firstly filters on a table and applies index during select but on 11 it gets all of the records on o table. I am using same dump, same configuration. I also tried to run mysqlcheck on 11th version but it doesn't help.
Any ideas here? Rewriting legacy queries might not be an option here, I need to fix it with the least intrusion possible.
Thank you in advance.

'New optimizer cost model
This is the main change that practically defines this release. Read about new optimizer cost model on its own page.' https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-11-0-0-release-notes/ Probably doesn't help I know..

there's unlikely to be a simple solution; every version will try to optimize better, resulting in some queries performing worse, since guesses are never going to be perfect.

For more Optimizer help, provide SHOW CREATE TABLE (for each relevant view and table)

ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON {query} will show the dfiference between estimates and real (r_..) in the query. Check table stats are up to date.
